# $f:[0,\infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is a continuous function such that $\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx < \infty$, what can be said about $f(n)$ for $n$ large.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

This is a previous year question from a competitive examination:

---

If $f:[0,\infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is a continuous function such that $\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx < \infty$, then which of the following are true:

1. $\{f_n\}$ is a bounded sequence.
2. $f(n) \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty$.
3. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ is convergent.

---

The answer given is *None of the above*.

I tried constructing some examples but none of them worked. Any ideas/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is asked way too often. (Change the first to $\{f(n)\}$ is a bounded sequence please.)  Here is another duplicate to view while this one gets shut down:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425712/integrability-of-f-on-bbb-r-does-not-necessarily-imply-the-convergence-of/4425776#4425776

Comment: Consider a function which is zero everywhere except with triangular “spikes” at integer values. By making these spikes increasingly narrow and tall, you can get a counterexample to all three of these.